# Remove a few particles?

Tags: mesh, particles

*I dont know how to explain the title feel free to change

I have downloaded a mesh that uses particles as grass and it is going through my knife mesh

[image]

I was wondering if there is anyway to get rid of those few strands?

Comment: did you try selecting the particle system and entering edit mode to remove the particles?

Comment: i need to only remove those 3 - 4 strands of grass , not the whole system

Comment: have you tried it with the vertex groups and weightpaint?

Comment: ah i tried the particle edit and that worked perfect!

Comment: I used the particle Edit , And made sure i had the right particle system selected.

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla would you like to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

To remove particles select the particle system by clicking on one of its particles then enter particle edit mode by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. In particle edit mode select the unwanted particles and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them.